# Why Can't I Push Onto Vue Array and Get It To Work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have come across an odd issue with Vue 2.  I have been using it for months now and love it.  But this issues it turning my hair gray.  This is the same format of how to do things that I have learned and use in many other pages and child components with no issue.  I may be too close to it to see something simple.  Hopefully.

To make this as simple as possible, here is my component:

**Here is the Page's Vue**

```
data: {
  openOrders: DataSets.CardTests
},
computed: {
  myOrders() {
    return this.openOrders.filter(x => {
      return ((x.FellowName !== undefined) && (x.FellowName.First === 'Sandra') && (x.FellowName.Last === 'Someone'));
    });
  },
  othersOrders() {
    return this.openOrders.filter(x => {
      return ((x.FellowName !== undefined) && ((x.FellowName.First + ' ' + x.FellowName.Last) !== 'Sandra Someone'));
    });
  },
  unassignedOrders() {
    return this.openOrders.filter(x => {
      return (x.FellowName === undefined);
    });
  },
},
mounted() {
  // Doing nothing here
}
```

The above 'should' fill my custom component called `order-set` with the computed value of `myOrders`:

```
<order-set ref="MyOrders"
           role-type="functional"
           title="My Work Queue"
           v-bind:is-multi-column="false"
           v-bind:is-collapsable="true"
           v-bind:can-view="true"
           v-bind:allow-view-swap="true"
           v-bind:as-table="false"
           v-bind:orders="myOrders">
</order-set>
```

There are two other instances of the `order-set` for the `othersOrders` and `unassignedOrders`.

The `DataSets.CardTests` is an array like the following:

```
CardTests: [{
  Id: 104,
  PatientName: {
    First: 'Richard',
    Middle: '',
    Last: 'Priebe'
  },
  DefaultMrn: {
    Type: 'CCF Main',
    Number: '123133',
    IsDefault: true
  },
  PatientDob: '2000-12-28T00:00:00',
  OrderDateTime: '2018-02-01T06:00:00-04:00',
  NursingUnit: 'M50',
  Site: 'CCF Main Campus',
  Bed: '18',
  TechnologistName: {
    First: 'Tim',
    Middle: null,
    Last: 'Fellows'
  },
  TestTypeCode: 'PORT',
  TestTypeDescription: 'Portable EEG'
}]
```

Granted, right now that is just junk test data but will eventually be coming from the database.

**All of the above renders perfectly and things are great!**

The second I start to make it a bit more 'real-world' where I gather the data once the page is loaded, like this:

```
data: {
  openOrders: []
},
mounted() {
  for (let o in DataSets.CardTests) {
    this.openOrders.push(DataSets.CardTests[o]);
  }
}
```

Nothing shows in my child `order-set` components.

However, in the Vue developer tools in Chrome, I see that `openOrders` has 10 records and the `myOrders`, `othersOrders` and `unassignedOrders` have 3, 2 and 5 records respectively.  Not to mention the 3 instances of my `order-set` component has its `orders` prop with the correct set of data as well.  **But**, the inner data element (`values` in this case) on the `order-set` component has no elements.

**OrderSet Component**

```
props: {
  orders: { type: Array, required: true, default() { return [] } }
},
data() {
  return {
    values: this.orders
  };
},
```

It is my understand that if you have a `prop` you may mutate, you should copy it into the `data` array so it is 'reactable`.

**UPDATE** - Simple portion of `order-set` component that does not work/show total records:

```
<div class="order-set">
  <div class="mb-2">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <h3><span class="highlight">{{ values.length }}</span> {{ title }}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what am I missing?  I have even tried `this.$nextTick` and `setTimeout` tests to see if it is a timing thing, to no avail.

Please help!

Comment: How are you passing data to your child elements? Would it be possible to paste your template code?

Comment: @ThomasLombart I have added an **UPDATE** near the bottom of the post.  It shows the `values` being used.  That `values` is what I use through the control to do whatever with.  Not the given prop of `orders`.

Comment: Make the Page components `data` option a function. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is the `values` in the data of the `OrderSet` component is not reactive when the prop `orders` changes. Let try with computed instead of the data

```
props: {
  orders: { type: Array, required: true, default() { return [] } }
},
computed: {
  values () {
    return this.orders
  };
},
```

**UPDATED**: why the properties of the data is not reactive in this case

> When defining a component, data must be declared as a function that
> returns the initial data object, because there will be many instances
> created using the same definition. If we use a plain object for data,
> that same object will be shared by reference across all instances
> created! By providing a data function, **every time a new instance is
> created we can call it to return a fresh copy of the initial data**.
>
> If required, a deep clone of the original object can be obtained by
> passing vm.$data through JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)).

So the `values` in this case will be cloned from the `openOrders`, resulting in changes on the `openOrders` is not affects to the `values`

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data

Comment: this works!  **Now I want to know why.**  Everything I have read says that the `data` element and its values ARE reactable.  What if I have to change my `values`?  Thank you very much though.

Comment: Computed reacts to changes in data

Comment: I have no idea why the data that assigned from the props is not reactive so I will investigate more and answer later if I found the answer.

For the remaining question, if you want to change the `values`, I think you can use `watcher` to watch the prop `orders` and manually update the values from the `data`. So you can do anything with the `values` after that.

Comment: Okay, thanks again @HuyDoDuc.  I look forward to seeing if you find an answer!

Comment: Properties of the `data` object are reactive in the sense that if they are updated in the logic of that vue instance, everything that depends on their values will reactively update (template, computeds, watchers, etc.). However, the `data` method which initializes the `data` object is fired only once upon the component's initialization. The `data` method does not behave like computed properties, where any dependant, reactive values will automatically update the returned value.

Comment: @HuyDoDuc that does make _some_ sense.  Thank you Again!

Answer (score -1):

Upon just looking at your code I believe you should have call the push inside the created function and not on mounted.

```
created: function() {
  for (let o in DataSets.CardTests) {
    this.openOrders.push(DataSets.CardTests[o]);
  }
}
```

The logic here is the way it executes. 
1. created 
2. computed 
3. mounted